# Exact file extension match with GetFiles()?

Tags: c#, regex, filtering, getfiles

I'd like to retrieve a list of files whose extensions match a specified string exactly.

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(someValidPath);
List<FileInfo> myFiles = new List<FileInfo>();
foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles("*.txt"))
{
    myFiles.Add(fi);
}
```

I get the files with extension `*.txt` but I also get files with the extension `*.txtx`, so what I've coded amounts to getting the files whose extension *starts with* `txt`.

This isn't what I want.  Do I need to grab all of the filenames and do a regular expression match to `"\\.txt$"` (I think), or test each filename string with `.EndsWith(".txt")`, etc.,   to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you do. Is it so hard, and why do you need regulare expressions?

Comment: Watch out, *every* answer forgets that Windows file names are case insensitive.  You can get .TXT as well.  Casing rules for file names are a bit nasty, you might want to check the string length.

Comment: @Hans: Good point. Does Fredrik's answer handle the case insensitivity issue?

Comment: Erm, it's better.  As I said, nasty, the file system keeps its own casing rules.  Fredrik's code works if it is just .txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhat of a workaround, but you can filter out exact matches with the `Where` extesion method:

```
foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles("*.txt")
    .Where(fi => string.Compare(".txt", fi.Extension, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0))
{
   myFiles.Add(fi);
}
```

Note that this will make a case insensitive matching of the extension.

Answer (score 3):

Using the AddRange feature of lists instead of doing the foreach loop and calling Add for each item returned by the expression below (which I save into the variable list).

```
var list = di.GetFiles("*.txt").Where(f => f.Extension == ".txt");
myFiles.AddRange(list);
```

I'm presuming you were just showing us a snippet of your code and myFiles already had values in it, if not, you could do instead.

```
List<FileInfo> myFiles = di.GetFiles("*.txt").Where(f => f.Extension == ".txt").ToList();
```

Comment: Edited and gave a bit more of an example.

Answer (score 2):

Regex might be overkill. Use the extension on FileInfo.

```
foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles("*.txt").Where(f => f.Extension == ".txt"))
{
     myFiles.Add(fi);
}
```

Comment: instead of foreach loop, you can do `myFiles.AddRange( the expression )`

Comment: @Chuck Savage: is "the expression" the part in the `foreach` loop following `in`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(someValidPath); 
List<FileInfo> myFiles =  
    (
        from file in di.GetFiles("*.txt")
        where file.Extension == ".txt"
        select file
    ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(someValidPath);
List<FileInfo> myFiles = new List<FileInfo>();
foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles("*.txt"))
{
   if (fi.Extension == ".txt")
      myFiles.Add(fi);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just add an **if** and check the last four characters of the filename?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C# 2.0
Isn't easier ?

```
string fileExtensionFilter = "*.txt";
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments));
            List<FileInfo> myFiles = new List<FileInfo>();
            foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles(fileExtensionFilter))
            {
                if (fi.Extension == fileExtensionFilter.Substring(1)) myFiles.Add(fi);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a user-supplied pattern so many of the other answers didn't suit me. I ended up with this more general purpose solution:

```
public string[] GetFiles(string path, string pattern)
{
    bool lastWildIsHook = false;
    if(pattern.EndsWith("?"))
    {
        pattern = pattern.Substring(0, pattern.Length - 1);
        lastWildIsHook = true;
    }
    var lastWildIndex = Math.Max(pattern.LastIndexOf("*"), pattern.LastIndexOf("?"));
    var endsWith = pattern.Length > lastWildIndex ? pattern.Substring(lastWildIndex + 1) : pattern;
    if(!lastWildIsHook)
        return Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern).Where(p => p.EndsWith(endsWith)).ToArray();
    else
        return Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern).Where(p => p.EndsWith(endsWith) || p.Substring(0, p.Length - 1).EndsWith(endsWith)).ToArray();
}
```